# How to make Post Installation Script for automated installation?

Tags: xubuntu, python, automation

- I have a ks.cfg which automates xubuntu installation
- Now after installing I want to run a script which will install my code, my doing few things like copying ssh key from server and doing git pull,setting supervisord,etc.
- Mostly i'll be doing ssh,git pull other post installation stuff using pythn fabric but the main question is how to run it on its own after installation and obviously only once.